# Extern specialization of some methods (not all) and keeping the class generic, is it possible?

Tags: c++, templates

I have this class : (common.h)

```
template <typename T>
class A{
public:
  A();
  int a(){
    return 42;
  }
  int b(){
    return 43;
  }
};
```

Let's say it's `A<int>` and `A<char>` are both instantiated in `main.cpp`

Is it possible to declare an (extern) specialized `A<int>::a()` that is defined in another file (`a.cpp`), while keeping everything else generic ?

Bonus : is it possible (in addition) to specialized `A<int>::b()` defined in yet another file (`b.cpp`)?

(The bonus question is more about to know if a compiler can emit only some method in the .o or if it should always emit the full specialized class)

By the way, I don't have any use case in mind, it's only to improve my knowledge about templates

Comment: Templates don't really permit anything to be "in secret" (if I understand your "other file but still generic" situation). Anything that uses a template with certain arguments without a full set of existing specializations for those arguments declared beforehand, is courting for nasal demons.

Comment: Well... This is not a "secret" : I would expect some kind of `template extern int A<int>::a();` declaration in .h, then some `template<> A<int>::a() {...}` in .cpp. (but I have found no syntax permitting it).
That way, when the compiler encounters a A<int>, it would know A<int>::a() is defined in some unit, and emit only the other methods. Then linker would complain if it does not have the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to declare an (extern) specialized A::a() that is defined in another file (a.cpp), while keeping everything else generic ?

Yes this is possible because explicit specialization(whether declaration or definition) behaves like non-template(declaration/definition) in this regard.

Below is a [working example](https://onlinegdb.com/nIP4Pjd-F) as per your given requirements:

**common.h**

```
#pragma once 
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class A{
public:
  A()=default;
  int a(){
    std::cout << "generic version of a\n";
    return 42;
  }
  int b(){
    std::cout << "generic version of b\n";
    return 43;
  }
  void c()
  {
      std::cout << "generic version of c\n";
  }
};

//declarations for specialization
template <> int A<int>::a();   //a is specialized for int(say) 
template <> int A<int>::b();  //b is specialized for int(say)
```

**a.cpp**

```
#include "common.h"
//definition
template <> int A<int>::a()
{
    std::cout << "specialized int version of a\n";
    return 100;
}
```

**b.cpp**

```
#include "common.h"
//definition
template <> int A<int>::b()
{
    std::cout << "specialized int version of b\n";
    return 101;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "common.h"


int main() {
   A<int> a1;
   a1.a();         // uses specialized int version of a 
   a1.b();         // uses specialized int version of b 
   a1.c();         //uses generic version of c
   
   A<char> a2;
   a2.a();        //uses generic version of a
   a2.b();        //uses generic version of b 
   
}
```